# How to Concatenate Integer Array to Single Integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, concatenation

Given the array [1,2,3], is there a method (other than just iteration) to convert it to the integer 123?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to avoid converting to and from a String, you can use `inject`:

```
[1,2,3].inject{|a,i| a*10 + i}
#=> 123
```

Comment: Clever -- took me a minute to work out what's going on here. The value of the accumulator `a` after each element in the `[1,2,3]` is evaluated, respectively, is: 0*10+1 = 1; then 1*10+2 = 12; then 12*10+3 = 123.

Comment: Welcome to all of you brought here by [AoC 2021 day 8](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/8)! :D

Comment: Thanks, glad to be here! :-D

Answer (score 18):

Just join the array and convert the resulted string to an integer:

```
[1,2,3].join.to_i
```

Answer (score 7):

Personally I would use

```
Integer([1,2,3].join, 10) #=> 123
```

since it has the nice side-effect of throwing an exception that you can deal with if you have non-numeric array elements:

```
>> Integer([1,2,'a'].join, 10) # ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer: "12a"
```

Compare this to `to_i`:

```
>> [1,2,'a'].join.to_i #=> 12
```

Comment: `Integer [0, 1, 1].join # => 9`, you want `Integer [0, 1, 1].join, 10 # => 11`.